# Postgis objects inside Leaflet circle

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, leaflet

How can I retrieve database objects from postgis database which are contained inside Leaflet circle object? I assume circle is only a point with some radius and not a polygon. I wonder can it be somehow converted to the polygon so I can read objects inside it from postgis database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) to buffer the point (Point geometry) at the center of your circle. In fact, this is the first example from the [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) documentation:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(
 ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'),
 50, 'quad_segs=8');
```

Notice the `quad_segs=8` argument is what indicates the "quality" of your resulting circular buffer.